# CEF - simple example

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to follow this guide to write minimally executable code that will request an HTML page and put it in std::string without rendering: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md

But there's no way I can do it.

All I could write was this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>


#include <include/cef_app.h>
#include "include/views/cef_window.h"
#include "include/cef_command_line.h"
#include "include/cef_sandbox_win.h"
#include "include/internal/cef_win.h"
#include <include/cef_client.h>
#include <include/wrapper/cef_helpers.h>


int main()
{

HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);

CefMainArgs main_args(hInstance);

int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, nullptr, nullptr);
if (exit_code >= 0)
{
    return exit_code;
}


CefSettings settings;
settings = { 0 };




CefInitialize(main_args, settings, nullptr, nullptr);
CefRunMessageLoop();

CefShutdown(); 
}
```

And I can't figure out what to do next.
Further in the documentation it is written that:

```
CefBrowser and CefFrame:
The CefBrowser and CefFrame objects are used for sending commands to the browser and for retrieving state information in callback methods. Each CefBrowser object will have a single main CefFrame object representing the top-level frame and zero or more CefFrame objects representing sub-frames. For example, a browser that loads two iframes will have three CefFrame objects (the top-level frame and the two iframes).

To load a URL in the browser main frame:

browser->GetMainFrame()->LoadURL(some_url);
```

But I can't figure out how to use it, where to insert it, in which part of the code. Yes, and this line of code does not work.Please help me understand.